# JPQL JOINS with nested SELECT

Tags: jpql, openjpa

Can I do something like this on JPQL?

```sql
SELECT NEW com.MyDTO(p.a, p.b, q.c, q.d)
FROM
(SELECT r.* FROM MyDTO1 r ) p
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT s.* FROM MyDTO2 s ) q
ON p.x = q.y
```

or similar?
(Above query has mixed with native and JPQL, so don't misunderstand)

I'm having a problem with this part I think.

```sql
FROM
(SELECT r.* FROM MyDTO1 r ) p
```

When I'm trying to execute I'm getting this error.

```
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [.....], unexpected token [(]
```

Thank you!

Comment: similar question answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67254869/3308908

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't. Quote from [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-subqueries):

> Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where
>   clauses.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can!

You have to use **[native queries](http://ci.apache.org/projects/openjpa/1.2.x/manual/jpa_overview_sqlquery.html)**. Here is an example:

```java
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TEST")    
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
String queryString = "SELECT ID FROM ( SELECT * FROM ADDRESS WHERE ID < 0)";
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryString);
List<BigDecimal> result = query.getResultList();
```