# SQL to JPQL join request

Tags: sql, jpa, join, jpql

Hopefully someone here can help me.

I have found the request I want to use on sqlDev :

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT ev.ID_AGENCE, MAX(ev.DATE_CREATION) DATE_CREATION
    FROM table1 ev
    WHERE ev.ID_AGENCE IN (326,324)
    GROUP BY ev.ID_AGENCE
) t2 ON t1.ID_AGENCE = t2.ID_AGENCE
    AND t1.DATE_CREATION = t2.DATE_CREATION
    order by t1.id_agence;
```

to keep only the closest date in a list, and only one per id (324 and 326 here in my exemple) :

```
324 22/10/18
324 21/10/18
324 20/10/18
326 10/08/18
326 09/08/18
326 07/08/18
326 06/08/18
326 05/08/18
326 04/08/18
326 03/08/18
326 02/08/18
326 01/08/18
```

I tried to translate to JPA (JPQL) :

```
final String requete = "SELECT e FROM ClasseJava JOIN " + 
                "( " + 
                    "SELECT f.id, MAX(f.dateCreation) dateCreation " + 
                    "FROM ClasseJava f " + 
                    "WHERE f.idAgence IN (326,324) " + 
                    "GROUP BY f.idAgence " + 
                ") "                        + 
                "t ON e.idAgence = t.idAgence " + 
                "AND e.dateCreation = t.dateCreation " + 
                "GROUP BY idAgence ";

final TypedQuery<ClasseJava> query = entityManager.createQuery(requete, ClasseJava.class);
query.setParameter("listIdAgence", listIdAgence);
return query.getResultList();
```

And I get the following error : *"The join association path is not a valid expression."*

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix the issue ?

Comment: I think you need to provide the `ClasseJava` and describe what you actually want to do instead of just pasting some queries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPQL JOINS with nested SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185542/jpql-joins-with-nested-select)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6952119/10495311) it's impossible to use a subquery in a join clause.
Same can be said about [Criteria API](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria#SubQuery) and [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-subqueries)

Maybe you can rewrite your query using a HAVING clause or by moving the subquery to a WHERE clause?

Comment: I made it work like this : 


final String requete = "SELECT e FROM classeJava e, " +
"( " +
"SELECT f.idAgence, MAX(f.dateCreation) dateCreation " +
"FROM classeJava f " +
"WHERE f.idAgence IN :listIdAgence " +
"GROUP BY f.idAgence " +
") " +
"t WHERE e.idAgence = t.idAgence " +
"AND e.dateCreation = t.dateCreation " +
"ORDER BY e.idAgence ";

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by removing the Join clause.

like this :

```
 final String requete = "SELECT e FROM classeJava e, " + 
"( " + 
"SELECT f.idAgence, MAX(f.dateCreation) dateCreation " + 
"FROM classeJava f " + 
"WHERE f.idAgence IN :listIdAgence " + 
"GROUP BY f.idAgence " + 
") " + 
"t WHERE e.idAgence = t.idAgence " + 
"AND e.dateCreation = t.dateCreation " + 
"ORDER BY e.idAgence ";
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Are you using EclipseLink? Only EclipseLink 2.4 or superior could support subquery on `FROM` clause using JPQL.