# QueryDSL - add subquery into FROM statement

Tags: spring-data, querydsl

I need to implement sql query like:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT a FROM b WHERE a.z = 1) WHERE rownum <=1;
```

How can I write such statement with QueryDSL (I am not using JPA and JDO - only clean sql)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Querydsl SQL emulates paging of all the supports databases, so you can write directly

```
query.from(a)
    .where(a.z.eq(1))
    .limit(1)
    .list(a);
```

If you need to write this via a subquery then like this

```
query.from(
  new SQLSubQuery().from(a).where(a.z.eq(1)).list(a).as(a))
 .where(rownum.loe(1))
 .list(a);
```

Comment: Is it just me but I'm not able to use the subquery solution as the .from() method requires an array of EntityPath<?>. The as() method returns a subtype of Expression.

Comment: @gouki Which Querydsl version do you use?

Comment: Hi Timo, it's version 3.4.2

Comment: There are enough form methods that should fit your case http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.4.2/apidocs/com/mysema/query/sql/ProjectableSQLQuery.html