# QueryDSL - add subquery into FROM statement using JPA

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Would you please help me to create QueryDSL construct for SQL like below using JPA Query. I am using 4.1.3.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT a FROM b WHERE a.z = 1) WHERE rownum <=1;
```

The Solutions mentioned is not working for me [QueryDSL - add subquery into FROM statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020049/querydsl-add-subquery-into-from-statement)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you implemented it?

Answer (score 0):

The below query:

`SELECT a FROM b WHERE a.z = 1`

does not have any `order by` clause, so default ordering will be applied. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899514/default-row-ordering-for-select-query-in-oracle) SO answer, the ordering is not predicted. So, I recommend adding the `order by` clause.

If this is just an example and the actual query contains `order by` then you can implement similar logic in a single query; rather than wrapping it into another query and get the first row, e.g. something like `(SELECT a FROM b WHERE a.z = 1 order by z)` with `rownum`. Below are the steps to do it via JPA way:

- Write a repository for that table (you can extend `PagingAndSortingRepository` as it already has some methods)
- Write a `findBy()` method that accepts `Pageble` argument (along with z), it would look like this:  `public List<T> findByZ(int z, Pageable pageable)`
- Call it with `Z` and `PageRequest`, e.g.:

  `final PageRequest page1 = new PageRequest(
        0, 1, Direction.ASC, "somefield"
     );`

It would apply the `limit/rownnum` based on db you are using and give you the record(s).

Comment: Hi Darshan, Thanks for the response. Basically, I am looking for the **QueryDSL** solution for above type of Subqueries(i.e. having subquery in FROM statement).