# QueryDSL - add subquery into FROM statement (2021)

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

In 2013 according to @Timo Westkämper (see [QueryDSL - add subquery into FROM statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020049/querydsl-add-subquery-into-from-statement)) it was possible to include a subquery in a FROM clause. Nowadays it seems this is not longer possible as JPQL specification does not allow it:

> (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_subqueries)
> Subqueries are restricted to the WHERE and HAVING clauses in this release. Support for subqueries in the FROM clause will be considered in a later release of the specification.

I don't get how is this possible. Can you confirm it's not possible to use subqueries in a FROM clause in querydsl 4.4.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the linked question carefully, Timo is talking about "Querydsl SQL". That's the QueryDSL module that directly emits SQL, completely bypassing JPA.

That is, you can use a subquery in a from clause when using plain SQL, but not when using JPQL.

That's why the method `com.querydsl.sql.SQLCommonQuery.from` has an [overload that takes a `SubQueryExpression`](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.4/apidocs/com/querydsl/sql/SQLCommonQuery.html#from-com.querydsl.core.types.SubQueryExpression-com.querydsl.core.types.Path-), while the method `com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLQuery.from` [doesn't have such an overload](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.4/apidocs/com/querydsl/jpa/JPQLQuery.html#from-com.querydsl.core.types.EntityPath...-).

Comment: This is the correct answer. However it is possible to use queries in the from clause in JPA using lateral joins or common table expressions using the Blaze-Persistence QueryDSL integration: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.5/core/manual/en_US/#querydsl-integration . Blaze-Persistence is a library that extends the JPA language with new features.