# QueryDSL: join subquery

Tags: querydsl

I would just like to check - for the QueryDSL version 3.1.1. - is it still impossible to join with a subquery, as is written in an answer here:
[JPQL / QueryDSL: join subquery and get aliased column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942108/jpql-querydsl-join-subquery-and-get-aliased-column)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, still the same restriction. The restriction comes from JPA, so there is not much to be done about it in Querydsl.

Comment: Does this restriction still exist (in JPA)?