# QueryDSL subquery with join

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa, querydsl, criteria-api

I'm new to criteria API, please help me to achieve the following query with Spring's QueryDSL:

```
SELECT a from TABLE_A a 
WHERE a.name IN ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT b.name from TABLE_C c 
    INNER JOIN c.table_B b 
    WHERE c.id = b.id AND c.id = :cId
) 
AND a.id = :aId
```

How to do the following:

```
public class TableASpecifications {

    public static Specification<TableA> workflow(Long aId, Long cId) {
        return (aRoot, query, cb) -> {
            Root<TableC> cRoot = query.from(TableC.class);
            final Join<TableC, TableB> tableB = cRoot.join("c", JoinType.LEFT);

            //PROBLEM how to get something like:
            return aRoot.get(TableA_.id).equals(aId)
               // PSEUDOCODE below
               .and(aRoot.get(TableA_.id).in(tableB.get("name")))
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Does JPA not allow this kind of queries? I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459327/querydsl-join-subquery), but it may be outdated.